# OpenGL ES settings for 2D games to perform better and/or save battery

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I read for example that the depth buffer is often not needed in 2D games and disabling it can increase performance quite a bit. Are there any other features I can disable or settings I can tweak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I talk about OpenGL ES in Android, but i'm quite sure it's similar in IOS environment. You can operate different optimization operation to work with Opengl ES.

**Optimization during OpenGL ES context**

When you create an OpenGL context, many "buffer" are created:

- Color buffer
- Depth buffer
- Stencil buffer

You can optimize OpenGL context creation with different operation:

1. reduce color buffer memory occupation: to do this, you must reduce pixel format: RBG_565 it's a good format
2. don't create depth buffer: you don't need it.
3. don't create stencil buffer:you don't need it.

This kind of optimization mainly reduce memory occupation. But you known, less memory you have to manage, faster you will be.

**Optimization during draw operations**

You probably work with OpenGL ES 2.+, so you have to write shader and vertex programs. There are different operation you can do:

1. Keep these GPU programs as simple as you can. To do this in Android i use NVIDIA Tegra Debugger. But it's because i have a tablet with Tegra X1 chipset.
2. Prefer [VBO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object) at client buffers
3. Precalculate everything you can: you have to draw every frame at max speed, so if something is statically defined (i.e.: matrix projection) calculate it before start to draw frames.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is nothing to do in this case. OpenGL is not a 3D Game Engine. 
In the default, every options you worry about are already disabled.

You won't make depth buffers because you don't need it. 
You won't use many matrices because you don't need  a projection matrix, a view matrix and so on.

In short, just don't enable what you don't need.

Don't make something in the typical rendering pipeline if you don't need it.

Don't make long shader codes because normally, you don't need that long shader codes in 2D game.